# VBA Insert Sheet Name in For Each Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a single workbook with more than 50 sheets. Each sheet is exactly the same number of rows and columns (data for each month is a sheet). I am using a For Each loop to copy a range of cells from each worksheet and paste into a Summary sheet. Then I'm deleting blank rows. How can I add the sheet name in a separate column during the For Each Loop. I want to know where the data from one sheet starts and ends.

```
Sub CopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not wks.Name = "Summary" Then
        wks.Range("C1:J100" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy_
        Destination:=Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0)        
    End If
  Next

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Data

```
Col A   B       C       D
Value1, Value2, Value3, Sheet Name Here
Value1, Value2, Value3, Sheet Name Here
Value1, Value2, Value3, Sheet Name Here
```

Comment: Assign `wks.Name` to a range/cell value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, and I have made some revisions to make the code a little more legible:

```
Sub CopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim destRange as Range


For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not wks.Name = "Summary" Then
        '## Get the range which will be copied:
        Set copyRange = wks.Range("C1:J100" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        '## Get the range where you will paste:
        Set destRange = Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0)
        '## Copy/Paste:
        copyRange.Copy destRange
        '## Fill in the source worksheet (copyRange.Parent) sheet name
        destRange.Offset(0,3).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count).Value = wks.Name


    End If
 Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Will `Rows.Count` need qualifying in the first 2 statements?

Comment: @MacroMan unlikely to *need* it and I don't want to confuse the OP with all sorts of optimizations like that.  The fringe case would be, if this procedure is somehow invoked while `ThisWorkbook` isn't active, *and* the`ThisWorkbook` is e.g., a 2003 XLS file but `ActiveWorkbook` is 2007+ ... While that's possible, it doesn't seem very likely.

Comment: I've always just erred on the side of caution with that and never questioned it, but as you say more of fringe case - and out of scope for this question so I'll leave it there - cheers :)

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed! I didn't want to painstakingly going through each sheet and add the sheet name and expand the copy range.

Comment: @MacroMan FWIW, I have probably *never* (literally!) bothered to qualify `Rows` object like that. I'm not saying it's a bad idea, only that I haven't found it to be necessary for *this* sort of use. Otherwise, it's always good idea to qualify ranges to sheets, and sheets to workbooks, etc. :)